# Teraform resource awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache not fully completing and failing plan?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, redis-cluster

I want to make sure I understand a message issued on `terraform apply`. I think it's trying to get the status of my Redis Serverless Cluster before whatever this awscc thing does to create it is done with it. Please let me know how to address stuff like this. How can I get Terraform to fully  wait for completion of the the awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache to be created or am I mis-understanding the meaning of this message when I do a terraform apply?

```
 Error: AWS SDK Go Service Operation Incomplete
│ 
│   with awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache.redis_cluster,
│   on main.tf line 281, in resource "awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache" "redis_cluster":
│  281: resource "awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache" "redis_cluster" {
│ 
│ Waiting for Cloud Control API service CreateResource operation completion
│ returned: waiter state transitioned to FAILED. StatusMessage: Serverless
│ Cache Name cannot be longer than 40 characters. (Service: ElastiCache, Status
│ Code: 400, Request ID: 6e1a2bf2-6fd9-46a4-88b6-f01b21e080c2). ErrorCode:
│ InvalidRequest
```

This is my main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

provider "awscc" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

variable "vpc_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "vpc id"
  default     = "vpc-41425a26"
}

data "aws_vpc" "existing_vpc" {
  id = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "elasticache_serverless_sg" {
  name        = "elasticache-serverless-sg"
  description = "Security group for ElastiCache Serverless Cache"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id  # Ensure this is set to the ID of your VPC

  # Inbound rules: Allow Redis traffic from within the VPC
  ingress {
    from_port   = 6379  # Default Redis port
    to_port     = 6379
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [data.aws_vpc.existing_vpc.cidr_block]
  }

  # Inbound rule: Allow traffic from the same security group (e.g., for replication)
  ingress {
    from_port       = 6379
    to_port         = 6379
    protocol        = "tcp"
    self            = true
  }

  # Outbound rules: Allow all outbound traffic (common practice)
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"  # -1 means all protocols
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "ElastiCache Serverless SG"
  }
}

resource "awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache" "this" {
  count = var.enabled && var.use_serverless ? 1 : 0

  serverless_cache_name = var.name
  description           = "${var.name} ElastiCache Redis Serverless"
  engine                = "redis"
  major_engine_version  = var.engine_version

  security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.elasticache_serverless_sg.id]
  subnet_ids          = var.subnets
  depends_on = [aws_security_group.elasticache_serverless_sg]
}

output "url" {
    value = "redis://${awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache.this[0].endpoint.address}:${awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache.this[0].endpoint.port}"
}
```

With variables:

```
variable "enabled" {
  description = "Set to false to prevent the module from creating any resources"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "replication_enabled" {
  description = "Set to false to diable replication in redis cluster"
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "cluster_mode_enabled" {
  description = "Set to false to diable cluster module"
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "name" {
  description = "Name of the application"
  type        = string
  default     = "value"
}

variable "tags" {
  description = "Additional tags (_e.g._ map(\"BusinessUnit\",\"ABC\")"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}

variable "subnets" {
  description = "AWS subnet ids"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}

variable "maintenance_window" {
  description = "Maintenance window"
  type        = string
  default     = "wed:03:00-wed:04:00"
}

variable "cluster_size" {
  description = "Cluster size"
  type        = number
  default     = 1
}

variable "instance_type" {
  description = "Elastic cache instance type"
  type        = string
  default     = "cache.t2.micro"
}

variable "engine_version" {
  description = "Redis engine version. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/supported-engine-versions.html"
  type        = string
  default     = "7"
}

variable "alarm_cpu_threshold_percent" {
  description = "CPU threshold alarm level"
  type        = number
  default     = 75
}

variable "alarm_ecpu_threshold_percent" {
  description = "ECPU threshold alarm level for elasticache serverless"
  type        = number
  default     = 75
}

variable "alarm_memory_threshold_bytes" {
  description = "Alarm memory threshold bytes"
  type        = number
  default     = 10000000 # 10MB
}

variable "alarm_data_threshold_percent" {
  description = "Data threshold alarm level for elasticache serverless"
  type        = number
  default     = 75
}

variable "notification_topic_arn" {
  description = "ARN of an SNS topic to send ElastiCache notifications"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "ok_actions" {
  description = "The list of actions to execute when this alarm transitions into an OK state from any other state."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}

variable "apply_immediately" {
  description = "Specifies whether any database modifications are applied immediately, or during the next maintenance window"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "port" {
  description = "Redis port"
  type        = number
  default     = 6379
}

variable "security_groups" {
  description = "List of  Security Group IDs to place the cluster into"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}

variable "subnet_group_name" {
  description = "Subnet group name for the ElastiCache instance"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "elasticache_parameter_group_family" {
  description = "ElastiCache parameter group family"
  type        = string
  default     = "redis7"
}

variable "replication_group_id" {
  description = "ElastiCache replication_group_id"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "parameters" {
  description = "A list of Redis parameters to apply. Note that parameters may differ from one Redis family to another"
  type = list(object({
    name  = string
    value = string
  }))
  default = []
}

variable "cluster_id" {
  description = "Cluster ID"
  type        = string
  default     = null
}

variable "create_elasticache_subnet_group" {
  description = "Create Elasticache Subnet Group"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "preferred_cache_cluster_azs" {
  description = "List of EC2 availability zones in which the replication group's cache clusters will be created. The order of the availability zones in the list is considered. The first item in the list will be the primary node. Ignored when updating"
  type        = list(string)
  default = [
    "ap-southeast-1a",
    "ap-southeast-1b",
  ]
}

variable "parameter_group_name" {
  description = "Existing Parameter Group name"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "snapshot_retention_limit" {
  description = "Number of days for which ElastiCache will retain automatic cache cluster snapshots before deleting them. For example, if you set SnapshotRetentionLimit to 5, then a snapshot that was taken today will be retained for 5 days before being deleted. If the value of snapshot_retention_limit is set to zero (0), backups are turned off. Please note that setting a snapshot_retention_limit is not supported on cache.t1.micro cache nodes"
  type        = number
  default     = 5
}

variable "auth_token" {
  description = "Password used to access a password protected server. Can be specified only if `transit_encryption_enabled = true`"
  type        = string
  default     = null
}

variable "kms_key_id" {
  description = "The ARN of the key that you wish to use if encrypting at rest. If not supplied, uses service managed encryption. Can be specified only if `at_rest_encryption_enabled = true`"
  type        = string
  default     = null
}

variable "num_node_groups" {
  description = "Number of node groups (shards) for this Redis replication group. Changing this number will trigger an online resizing operation before other settings modifications. Required unless `global_replication_group_id` is set"
  type        = number
  default     = 2
}

variable "replicas_per_node_group" {
  description = "Number of replica nodes in each node group. Valid values are 0 to 5. Changing this number will trigger an online resizing operation before other settings modifications."
  type        = number
  default     = 1
}

# ElastiCache Serverless
variable "use_serverless" {
  description = "Use serverless ElastiCache service"
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "max_data_storage" {
  type        = number
  description = "The maximun cached data capacity of the Serverless Cache in GB"
  default     = 10

  validation {
    condition     = var.max_data_storage >= 1 && var.max_data_storage <= 5000
    error_message = "The max_data_storage in GB value must be between 1 and 5,000."
  }
}

variable "max_ecpu_per_second" {
  type        = number
  description = "The maximum ECPU per second of the Serverless Cache"
  default     = 1000

  validation {
    condition     = var.max_ecpu_per_second >= 1000 && var.max_ecpu_per_second <= 15000000
    error_message = "The max_ecpu_per_second value must be between 1,000 and 15,000,000."
  }
}

variable "daily_snapshot_time" {
  type        = string
  description = "The daily time range (in UTC) during which the service takes automatic snapshot of the Serverless Cache"
  default     = "18:00"
}

variable "snapshot_arns_to_restore" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "The ARN's of snapshot to restore Serverless Cache"
  default     = []
}

variable "user_group_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "The ID of the user group Elasticache"
  default     = ""
}
```

These are myvars.tfvars:

```
enabled                           = true
create_elasticache_subnet_group   = true
use_serverless                    = true
subnets                           = ["subnet-dce5d0bb","subnet-922a66db"]
vpc_id                            = "vpc-41425a26"
```

Comment: maybe I am misinterpreting the message too...but by reading the error message it seems to me that the cache name is too long `Serverless
│ Cache Name cannot be longer than 40 characters` what's the value of var.name ?

Comment: @Leonardo Thank you, you were right. Please reply as an answer so I can give you credit. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the problem is in the server cache name variable length:

```
Serverless
│ Cache Name cannot be longer than 40 characters.
```

However, for future needs in case you have to wait for something to be marked as ready (for example some local script that may work asynchronously) you can introduce Terraform [Time Sleep resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep) between your existing resources and play with `depends_on` attribute which is present in all modules.

Answer (score 0):

@Leonardo we are getting the below error while running the above code any help on this please

```
Error: AWS SDK Go Service Operation Incomplete

 with awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache.this[0],
 on radis.tf line 36, in resource "awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache" "this":
36: resource "awscc_elasticache_serverless_cache" "this" {

Waiting for Cloud Control API service CreateResource operation completion
 returned: waiter state transitioned to FAILED. StatusMessage: Input
 subnetIds are invalid: [subnet-xxxxxxx, subnet-xxxxxxx,
 subnet-xxxxxxx]. (Service: ElastiCache, Status Code: 400, Request
ID: c050e51e-00fa-xxxxxxxx). ErrorCode: InvalidRequest
```

Comment: I suggest double checking that you have at least 3 subnets (the minimum is either 2 or 3). I'm not sure if there's a requirement for different AZs.